# first material UI button hides

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material UI buttons like this

```
      <main className="content">
        <div className="buttons">
          <Button
            variant="contained"
          ></Button>
          <br />
          <br />
          <Button
            variant="contained"
          >
            Text
          </Button>
        </div>
      </main>
```

```
.content {
  padding-left: 280px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}

.buttons {
  padding-top: 20px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
```

but for some reason the first button hides and I can only see the lower half of it on my screen. Here's a codesandbox example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pond-4bqgm?file=/src/page.css:0-179

Comment: Your first button doesn't have text in it.

Comment: Where are you applying styles? Material UI has own useStyle and makeStyle that uses js object. But you can also use your own css. You must import the css in React, and also you must add className to reference .`.buttons`. Otherwise, it should be the original tag named `button`. Also Material UI does not render Button in a button tag, but in a div containing other div, label, span and button tags, each with special Class names. So I don't see link from Button and CSS here.

Comment: Indeed, you didn't have the very basic text on it. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first button doesn't have a text.

```
<Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={() => history.push("./overfitting")}
          >I'm here</Button>
```